# How to uniquely identify value of a column in a row of a table (that has many rows) using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".viewLink").click(function() 
            {
                var requisiteId = $('.viewLink').attr('value');
                alert(requisiteId);
                var dataString = 'id='+ requisiteId;

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkRequestExe.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#individualRequisite").show();
                    $("#eachRequisite tr").remove();
                    if (data != false)
                    {   
                        $("#eachRequisite").prepend(data);
                        $("#eachRequisite").hide().fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                }

                });

                return false;
            });         
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:752px; height:330px; overflow:auto;">
            <table class="record" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr style="background-color:#808080; font-size:12px; color:white; font-weight:bold;">
                    <td width="400">Title</td>
                    <td width="100">Requestor</td>
                    <td width="145">Date Request</td>
                    <td width="80">Status</td>
                </tr>

                <?
                    $count=0;   
                    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results))
                    {       
                        $requisiteId = $data["RequisiteId"];
                        $title = $data["Title"];
                        $userId = $data["UserId"];
                        $date = $data["DateRequest"];
                        $status = $data["Status"];

                        $color = ($count%2==0)?'CCCCFF':'E8E8E8';
                ?>
                        <tr style="background-color:#<?=$color?>; color:black; font-weight:bold;">
                            <td><?=$title?></a></td>
                            <td><?=$userId?></a></td>
                            <td><?=$date?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?
                                    if ($status == 0)   
                                    {
                                        $word = "Pending";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $word = "Completed";
                                    }
                                    echo "<a href='#individualRequisite' class='viewLink' value='$requisiteId'>$word</a>";
                                ?>
                            </td>       

                        </tr>
                <?
                        $count++;
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

How can I uniquely identify the class viewLink so whenever any anchor with that class is clicked, the value of the anchor("requisiteId")is passed into jquery and subsequently being passed into another script to handle?

The current problem is that it will continuously being replaced with the latest requisiteId.
Any solution?

The problem is here [`var requisiteId = $('.viewLink').attr('value');`] 
where the `requisiteId` will always be the same even I clicked the anchor of a different row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of the line

```
var requisiteId = $('.viewLink').attr('value');
```

you want

```
var requisiteId = $(this).attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that there are multiple viewLink objects, so when you run $('.viewLink'), you're actually getting back a list of items.

If you call .attr() on the list, you'll get the first one back.  You need to do this:

```
$(".viewLink").click(function() 
{
     var requisiteId = $(this).attr('value');
```

Which will give you back the attr of the target item.